# (Fixed) CRM_Custom_Import_Form_Summary error when sending one of email

Tags: civimail, joomla

When trying to send an individual mail I get a 500 error
POST /administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/activity/email/add&action=add&cid=7070&selectedChild=activity&atype=3&snippet=json&crmAngularModules=af,afCore,afsearchGrants,angularFileUpload,api4,checklist-model,crmDialog,crmResource,crmSearchDisplay,crmSearchDisplayTable,crmSearchTasks,crmUi,crmUtil,dialogService,ngSanitize,ui.bootstrap,ui.sortable HTTP/1.0

and a PHP error
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Declaration of CRM_Custom_Import_Form_Summary::preProcess() must be compatible with CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Summary::preProcess(): void in /var/www/vhosts/springsdancecompany.org.uk/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Custom/Import/Form/Summary.php on line 13', referer: https://springsdancecompany.org.uk/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contact/view&reset=1&cid=7070

Running  5.54.0 on Joomla 3.10 (at present due to errors I am unable to upgrade further)

Problems seemed to start with 5.54.0 upgrade and what I presume is the move of afforms into the core product

Comment: You can mark it "fixed" by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer, under the up-down arrows.  That also prevents stackexchange from reposting this periodically as unsolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said drupal but that url is joomla, so I think this is that joomla issue where you have to delete the civi code folder completely and replace it with the new version, but that isn't natively how joomla works, so you still have code files from the earlier version in the tree. The file CRM/Custom/Import/Form/Summary.php no longer exists in 5.54 but it's still there in your files and getting in the way.

I'd start by just deleting/renaming that file and see how it goes.

See also the last paragraph in this section: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/joomla/#install-the-extension

Comment: That fixed it - thanks so much :-)