# Upgrade to 5.57 failure in Joomla 3.10

Tags: joomla

I have just upgraded CiviCRM to 5.57 in my Joomla 3.11 environment and instantly it tells me that the following error is triggered:

Fatal error: Declaration of CRM_Custom_Import_Form_Summary::preProcess() must be compatible with CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Summary::preProcess(): void in /homepages/33/d128624839/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Joomla/BackfordAreaHistory/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Custom/Import/Form/Summary.php on line 13

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Fixed) CRM\_Custom\_Import\_Form\_Summary error when sending one of email](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/43142/fixed-crm-custom-import-form-summary-error-when-sending-one-of-email)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a duplicate of [(Fixed) CRM_Custom_Import_Form_Summary error when sending one of email](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/43142/fixed-crm-custom-import-form-summary-error-when-sending-one-of-email).

Delete this file: CRM/Custom/Import/Form/Summary.php

Answer (score 1):

The issue is now resolved, but not using the response given.

Just after experiencing the error, I attempted an upgrade to Joomla 4 and that borked as well. This meant, I then had to rebuild the site from scratch. During that process, I discovered the underlying reason for both failures - my hosting provider's file number limits were being breached (Grrrh!!).

Thanks anyway for the response.